# Why magento 2.1.9 not sending confirmation email after successful password reset?

Tags: magento2, email

In magento2 - after reset password conformation mail not send.

We have default functionality in `Magento 1.x`  but how is it possible in `Magento 2.x`?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: have you tried to enable cron job?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Please try with SMTP module and config settings :

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

After install put your email id and password in settings and send test mail

possible to try to install module via composer.

```
composer require magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp
```

**hope its work for you**